# Best Practices for Implementing Private Events in Blockchain: Restricting Event Visibility to Specific Addresses

Tags: events, blockchain-events

I'm exploring a nuanced aspect of blockchain functionality and seeking community insights. In blockchain systems, events are typically public, accessible to any address. However, I'm interested in developing a mechanism where certain events are only readable by a specific address or a set of addresses.

One approach I've considered is encrypting the event content, but I'm curious if there are more efficient or standardised practices in the blockchain community for this purpose.

To illustrate, consider a scenario where you add a friend and emit a 'friend request' event. Ideally, only the parties involved in this event - the sender and the recipient - should have the ability to read its contents.

Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to effectively implement this kind of privacy within a blockchain environment, ensuring that specific events remain private and are only accessible to authorised addresses?

Thanks!